# Running a Tor-Relay on a private network restricts other services (eg netflix)

Tags: relays

This is not so much a question but a post for completion. I hope this meets the community standards.

I am running a tor-relay in my home network. Naturally, it is reachable on my public IP that is provided by my ISP. When I browse the internet, I do so on the very same IP.

On May 21st 2020 (plus-minus) I recognized that Netflix was restricting most of its content and displaying a `F7111-5059` error. It seems that netflix recognizes my relay's IP/my public IP as a VPN connection and blocks any content.

Can anyone confirm this case? Or does anyone has found a way to circumvent this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Is your relay an exit relay? If so then this is unfortunately typical since these services can't tell the difference between your personal traffic and traffic from the exit relay. Instead they just decide to block all traffic from the IP regardless of any collateral damage.

Is your relay a non-exit relay? I haven't personally run into this problem, but this happens once in a while when these services block IP addresses of all relays and not just exit relays. It doesn't make sense for them to do this, but these services either don't care if they block some small fraction of users, or don't understand how Tor works.

In either of these cases, there's no way to have your IP address unblocked other than contacting the company, or shutting down your relay and hoping that they unblock you. It may also be possible to run your relay with IPv4 only and use IPv6 only for personal browsing (so that they have different IP addresses), but I haven't tried this.